# Onclick should not fire when onblur fails

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onblur

I have a HTML table with multiple rows and columns.
I have bill number, bill date, Description, Amount etc as columns.
In Bill date column, I have defined onclick and onblur events.
onclick - shows a calendar and user can pick a date.
onblur - will validate the date whether it is within a period or not and so on.

Now, let us assume there are 4 lines.
I click on Date column of 4th line. Calendar appears. I select a date.
Now, I click on Date column of 3rd line. Calendar appears. Same time the onblur for 4th line executes and returns an error message. Now here my system gets confused. I want on failure of validation on 4th line, onclick of 3rd line should not fire and my cursor should still be in 4th line itself.

Is it possible or my ask is too much ? Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you keep a global variable as flag and use its value to track in what status your input is.

See below:

```
var bInEditMode = false;

function onclickevent() {
    if ( bInEditMode ) return;

    bInEditMode = true;
    // TODO: call your calendar code
}

function onblurevent() {
    // TODO: call your testing code
    bInEditMode = false;
}
```

Comment: Answer seems to be workable. But still finding few problems. This is due to the situation in the code. I populate the values from Excel file. All the validation takes place. The Boolean becomes false. No, I am trying to click on any Date column, Calendar is not opening... Need to put in some brain work into it. Will try to do...